# How to patch a package that is not in my "dependencies" in pnpm?

Tags: pnpm

I want to patch a package that is not listed in my "dependencies" but is a dependency of a package that is listed in my "dependencies" section. Is it possible to do this using pnpm?

Answer (score 0):

**Nested packages**

If you are trying to patch a package at, e.g. node_modules/package/node_modules/another-package you can just put a / between the package names:

npx patch-package package/another-package
It works with scoped packages too

npx patch-package @my/package/@my/other-package

https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

Comment: `ds300/patch-package` recommends to use `pnpm patch` in pnpm. Unfortunately, it's unclear how to patch transitive dependencies using `pnpm patch` command.

Comment: have you tried by utilizing `/` between dependencies?